# How to get number of query result incase insert and select?

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, sql-server

i'm trying to get the number of records affected when using select and insert query

i have tried this for insert query:

```
recordSet.rowsAffected
```

and this for select query:

```
recordSet.length
```

but none of them worked.

this is my code:

```
router.route('/').post((req, res)=> {
var postData = req.body; // get post params
    //  res.json({"message":req.body.firstName});
connection.connect().then(function(){
  var request = new sql.Request(connection);
  request.input('email', sql.VarChar(45), postData.email)
   .input('password', sql.VarChar(45), postData.password)
   .input('category', sql.VarChar(45), postData.category)
   .query('select * from Buyer where password = @password and category = 
@category and email = @email')
   .then((recordSet)=>{
       if (recordSet.length == 0) {
       request.input('buyerId', sql.VarChar(45), uid.v4())
        .input('firstName', sql.VarChar(45), postData.firstName)
        .input('lastName', sql.VarChar(45), postData.lastName)
        .input('email', sql.VarChar(45), postData.email)
        .input('password', sql.VarChar(45), postData.password)
        .input('phoneNumber', sql.VarChar(45), postData.phoneNumber)
        .input('category', sql.VarChar(45), postData.category)
        .query('insert into Buyer(buyer_id, first_name, last_name, email, 
 password, phone_number, category) values(@buyerId, @firstName, @lastName, 
 @email, @password, @phoneNumber, @category)')
        .then((recordSet)=>{
            if(recordSet.rowsAffected == 1){
              res.status(buyerCreatedCode).send("Account Created as 
 Buyer.");
            }else{
              res.status(buyerNotCreatedCode).send("Account not Created as 
 Buyer.");
            }
              connection.close();
            }).catch((err)=>{
              res.json({"error in adding buyer":err});
              connection.close();
            });
          }else{
            res.status(buyerNotCreatedCode).send("This Account already 
 exists.");
            connection.close();
          }
          }).catch((err)=>{
            res.json({"error in checking buyer":err});
            connection.close();
          });
        }).catch((err)=>{
          res.json({"error connection":err});
          connection.close();
        });
      });
```

so i expect the buyer is inserted to the database if the select query returns 0 records, if the it returns records then the buyer is not inserted(but it inserts anyway).

my question is how to get the number of affected rows correctly so the task performs correctly?.
thanks in advance.

Comment: What package are you using?

Comment: i'm using mssql

Comment: Would it be easier to use a primary key, try the insert, catch the crash when it already exists and do something else (update? nothing?)

Comment: @CaiusJard That is a bad idea. It assumes that there is a Unique Key on the three fields (which is not guaranteed), and can end up trapping other errors and reporting them as duplicate key / "Buyer already exists" errors.

Comment: @LaughingVergil erm.. what? This code is for determining if an account exists; my point is the database should be the ultimate authority on what determines an account already exists, not a "do a select and then some milliseconds later do an insert in a potentially multi user system". Do it properly, define a good unique constraint

Comment: @CaiusJard - Look at the code above. It checks if a duplicate record exists by SELECTing based on email, category, and password. If there isn't a UNIQUE constraint or index on those three fields, then simply INSERTing the row will succeed (since the PK appears to be a GUID). Also, unless the TRY... CATCH block is written to handle other errors correctly, then any error will cause the CATCH block to report a duplicate, when the actual error is, oh, the data drive is full, or there was a deadlock, or...

Comment: If there isn't a unique constraint then *make one*.. When did SO implement a rule that we have to persist with the crappy way someone has devised a solution and help them get it going, rather than suggest better ways of doing it?

Comment: thank you very much guys you opened my eyes on a lot of things i will consider the suggestions you gave me, i think i been following some sh***y tutorial.

Comment: but one thing i don't understand,what is GUID? and why the insert is always going to succeed?@CaiusJard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should move most of your code's functionality into the SQL code, create a stored procedure from it, and call that with your values.

As an example, your stored procedure could look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddBuyer 
    @email varchar(45), -- too small. up to 100
    @password varchar(45),
    @category varchar(45),
    @firstname varchar(45),
    @lastName varchar(45),
    @phoneNumber varchar(45)  -- Couldn't this be smaller?
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @buyerId uniqueidentifier
        , @error int

    -- Recommended - return the message and the ID from this procedure

    SELECT @buyerId = BuyerId
    FROM Buyer
    WHERE email = @email
        AND password = @password
        AND category = @category

    IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0
    BEGIN
        -- Return the actual existing ID 
        SELECT @buyerId as BuyerId, 
            'This Account already exists.' as StatusMsg
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        SET @buyerId = NewID()  -- Generate UniqueIdentifier
        insert into Buyer(
            buyer_id, 
            first_name, 
            last_name, 
            email, 
            password, 
            phone_number, 
            category
        ) 
        values(
            @buyerId, 
            @firstName, 
            @lastName, 
            @email, 
            @password, 
            @phoneNumber, 
            @category
        );

        SET @error = @@ERROR
        IF @error > 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT CAST(NULL as uniqueidentifier) as BuyerId, 
                'Account not Created as Buyer. (Status=' + Cast(@error as varchar(10)) + ')' as StatusMsg
        END
        ELSE
        BEGIN
            SELECT @buyerId as BuyerId,
                'Account Created as Buyer.' As StatusMsg
        END
    END 
END
```

When you execute this, you will return a one row recordset. It consists of the BuyerId value (NULL in case of an error) and the appropriate message text.

Variations include returning the values in OUTPUT variables, TRY...CATCH error trapping, and others.

Comment: This is, of course, the DBA answer to a lot of things - "use a stored procedure".. What I can't understand is why you're advocating reinventing a "don't allow duplicate record" wheel that databases already do perfectly well using intrinsic functionality

Comment: Well, there are several possible reasons, and the most major ones involve transactions. Consider that "XACT_ABORT must be set ON for data modification statements in an implicit or explicit transaction against most OLE DB providers, including SQL Server." This means that, if you need to execute code in a transaction (to update many values across tables coherently, for example) then trying to add the buyer record with a TRY...CATCH to handle duplicates means that the whole transaction will be rolled back, which may not be what you want to happen.

Comment: And, even if that is OK right now, in the future it may not be. The stored procedure wouldn't need to be changed, but a code block with TRY...CATCH would need to be changed. Additionally, the added functionality of returning the existing ID (instead of needing to find that value) if you need it for any purpose will frequently more than compensate for the additional overhead of the lookup. Finally, for the TRY...CATCH approach to work, there must be a UNIQUE constraint against the fields involved, which may neither exist or be desired.